# input validation with std::ifstream

Tags: c++, validation, ifstream, coverity

I'm reading a file using something like:

```
    std::ifstream is( file_name );
    std::string s;

    if( !is.good() ) {
        std::cout << "error opening file: " << file_name << std::endl;
    } else {
        while( !is.eof() ) {
            s.clear();
            is >> s;
            if (s.empty())  continue;
            if (s.size() < 1 || s.size()>0x7FFFFFFF ) {
               std::cout << "implausible data" << std::endl;
               continue;
            }
            char *ss = new char[ s.size() + 1 ]; // COVERITY bails out
            // do something with the data
            delete[]ss;
        }
    }
```

When I analyse the above code with the static code analysis tool [coverity](http://coverity.com/) (free version), the line marked with *COVERITY bails out* throws an error:

```
 Untrusted value as argument (TAINTED_SCALAR)
   tainted_data: Passing tainted variable > s.size() + 1UL to a tainted sink.
```

I understand that I must not trust any data read from a file, but I fail to see how to validate the data at this stage.
I'm already checking that `s.size()` is within a plausible (albeit rather large) range in the `if`-clause above the erroneous line.

So why is coverity throwing a warning at me?

Also, which other strategies for input-validation should I apply?

Comment: Should not really loop on `eof()`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Instead of testing `s.empty()` it is better to test if the read succeeded: `while(is >> s) { /* reading s succeeded here */ ... }`

Comment: Maybe the code analyzer fails at realizing that `s.size()` will return the same value on all three invocations.  Did you try assigning the return value to a variable and use that one?

Comment: Also, on 32bit systems, you can't allocate `0x80000000` bytes, but your code tries.  Maybe that's the problem?  You need to lower that max by a bit more?

Comment: @5gon12eder your trick indeed fixes the issue with coverity.

Comment: Fine, I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following section

```
if (s.empty())
  continue;
if (s.size() < 1 || s.size() > 0x7FFFFFFF)
  {
    std::cout << "implausible data" << std::endl;
    continue;
  }
char * ss = new char[s.size() + 1];
```

the validation logic relies on the important fact that `s.size()` will return the same value every time it is called.  While in this case, we (humans) know this will be true, a static code analyzer might fail at realizing that.

As a workaround, try introducing a local variable and use that one.

```
const std::size_t length = s.size();
if (!length)
  continue;
if (length < 1 || length > 0x7FFFFFFF)
  {
    std::cout << "implausible data" << std::endl;
    continue;
  }
char * ss = new char[length + 1];
```

Here, it is simple for the analyzer to tell that `length` will not change its value.

Whether or not such coding around the limitations of static analyzer tools is worthwhile is open to debate.  The [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Syntactic-Conventions) discourage it.

> Don’t make the program ugly just to placate static analysis tools such as lint, clang, and GCC with extra warnings options such as `-Wconversion` and `-Wundef`. These tools can help find bugs and unclear code, but they can also generate so many false alarms that it hurts readability to silence them with unnecessary casts, wrappers, and other complications. For example, please don’t insert casts to void or calls to do-nothing functions merely to pacify a lint checker.

Personally, I don't feel too bad about it as long as the readability of the code doesn't suffer too much.  In corner cases, adding a comment that explains why things are done the way they are done might be a good idea.